# Sending Values to Iframe HTML PAGE

Tags: iframe, asp-classic

I have an asp page and in asp page there is iframe having HTML page. What i need is to send two values from asp page to inner HTML page. How is it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass them as query string vars:

```
<iframe src="page.asp?var1=<%=var1%>&var2=<%=var2%>"></iframe>
```

Comment: `&amp;`! Your vars are not entity names.

Comment: @Anil Kumar: If it is html page how will  you process the query string vars? Shouldn't it be asp page too?

Comment: @ sAc..Thanks for reply...Yes i know but i it is a HTML template( NEEDED HTML) which brigs dynamic news article. so all the things are going well but i need the article id of asp page to send farward using javascript.

Comment: @Anil Kumar: Yes just replace name and extension in my answer in the `src` to html eg `src="pageName.html?var1=<%=var1%>&var2=<%=var2%>"` and you get the vars for url using `Request.QueryString("Name")`